# wordpress - display all content of a post (ignore "more")

Tags: wordpress

On a mobile version of my site, I want to ignore the  tag and display the full text of every post. How can I do this? This cuts off the text and inserts (more...):

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PAGE.PHP underneath this code  you are using EXCERPT function, either remove EXCERPT from there.